# Send a dynamic variable with HTTP client API consume Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

```
public function index($word)
    {
        
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'app_id' => 'xxxxxxx',
            'app_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        ])->get('https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/lemmas/en/{word_id}')->json();
       return $response 
    }
```

**How can I send the variable $word in the `{word_id}` in this function**
I Have Tried

```
(https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/lemmas/en/{word_id}',['word_id'=>$word]);
GOt error
```

Comment: I think you can concat it, why not?

Comment: @Miqayel Can You explain?

Comment: Like this `->get('https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/lemmas/en/'.$word)`

Comment: instead of ``{word_id}`` pass ``${word}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat it like this `get('https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/lemmas/en/'.$word)` or you can use double quotes like this `get("https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/lemmas/en/$word")`